# Not able to find following element using id,Xpath,linkText

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to access the `<a>` element that has the text "001". I tried using the DOM ID, XPath, and linkText, as well as this JavaScript, but I am unable to find it. How can I accomplish this?

This is the JavaScript I'm using to find the `<a>` element:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("campcode")).click();
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="Layout">
  <div class="PageTitle">
    <div class="Primary-Container Rad5Top">
      <div class="Secondary-Container Rad5Top">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
          <div id="SupplyChainTabs">
            <div id="opportunitiesDetails">
              <table id="ActionLinks" class="ColRow-Table internal-qualification tablesorter" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th id="CAMPID" width="250" align="left" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <th id="CommunityName" width="200" align="left" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <th id="ProdCode" width="200" align="left" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <th id="Prospects" width="150" align="left" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <th id="TS" width="200" align="left" style="cursor: pointer;">
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                      <a id = "OB.2000003,OB.2000052,OB.2000053,OB.2000054,OB.2000055,OB.2000056,OB.2000057,OB.2000058" class="" onclick="return ButtonClick(this);" href="#f">001</a> <!-- THE ELEMENT -->
                    </td>
                  <td valign="top"> THQS</td>
                  <td valign="top"> THQS</td>
                  <td valign="top"> 8</td>
                  <td valign="top"> 18/09/2014 13:01:13</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: In what way is your JavaScript not working?

Comment: its stop when come to this page and not able to select the element (001) i tried by using xpath as well but not able to select that one as well  xpath for it(/html/body/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a)

Comment: HTMl code for it --   <a id="OB.2000003,OB.2000052,OB.2000053,OB.2000054,OB.2000055,OB.2000056,OB.2000057,OB.2000058" onclick="return ButtonClick(this);" href="#f" class="">001</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='opportunitiesDetails']//a[text()='001']")).click();
```